# Count up and down elegantly

Tags: c++, math, logic

I'm trying to make a flashing object, i.e., increment it's alpha value from 0 to 255 (gradually) and then back down to 0, and repeat.

Is there a way I can do this without using some boolean? Getting it to increment is easy:

```
alpha = time.elapsed()%256;
```

But what's a nice way to get it to count back down again after that?

Comment: Why do you need this? Please don't say "performance". if you want to make a flashing object, that means at most 60 updates per second, which means that no matter how you do this, it makes zero difference performance-wise. So what is the reason for making your code harder to read?

Comment: @jalf: Actually the goal was to make it easier to read. Using a couple if statements to track whether it's currently incrementing or decrementing complicates it. If this can be done on one line, I'd say that's simpler.

Comment: Shorter, but I wouldn't call it simpler or more readable. if it was so "simple", why did you need to ask this question? You couldn't figure it out yourself, so what makes you believe you'll be able to figure it out when you encounter the code 3 months from now?

Comment: @jalf: Because sometimes after hours of programming your head doesn't function properly and you get stumped on the easier things. Trust me, I'll be able to understand it in 3 months.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

How about using a sin function, that way the fading is more pleasant and you'll get what you want.

Comment: `alpha = static_cast<int>(sin((time.elapsed()%10)*(M_PI/10))*255);`? I think? 10 can be replaced with whatever interval you wish, and optimally you would replace `M_PI/10` with a constant (e.g. `const double frac = M_PI/10;`)

Comment: Hrm... you're right, I think this does look ever so slightly better. A period of 1000ms is pretty decent.

Answer (score 14):

Maybe you could do it this way:

```
alpha = abs((time.elapsed() % 510) - 254);
```

Comment: +1 had to stare at that for a second to wrap my brain around it

Comment: I think it should be 511 and 255, no? 256 shouldn't be included. Anyway, knew there had to be a trick like this, I just forgot about `abs`ing it. Thanks! Works great.

Comment: This will start at abs(0 % 510 - 254) = 254. That seems pretty awkward.

Comment: Oh no... then 255 repeats twice... should be 510 and 255 then?

Comment: @Johan: You could add a `+254` inside the modulo to have it start at 0.

Comment: @Mark: I don't see where it includes 256 or where 255 repeats... For which numbers does it give wrong results?

Comment: Ah... nvm, you're right sth. It just looks funny because it starts at 254. I'm just confusing myself.

Answer (score 5):

abs(((x + 255) % 510) - 255) will go linearly from 0 to 255 for x between 0 and 255, and linearly from 255 to 0 for x between 255 and 510. Then it repeats (with period 510 of course).

Comment: I guess technically this is the right answer since I said increment first. sth's answer starts with decrementing, but it's fewer operations, so I actually prefer it. Either way is fine ;)